# Use of not without an Auxillary

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is the below sentence grammatically correct?

> Know not what you know.

Comment: Yes. It's grammatically correct. Compare with similar structures, that may help you see the grammar here.

Comment: You should strongly consider becoming a regular on English Language Learners Q&A ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: meta: Is it time ELU starts calling itself "Advanced English" or something like it (if only to suggest that it has a *younger* sister on SE)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that the OP is confining the analysis to imperative sentences / sentence fragments, and
2. Switching to a more tractable example (the original looks suspiciously like a corrupt quote (' ...he knows not what he knows...'):

> Come, Lord, and tarry not.

(line from an old hymn)

Here, the archaic negative imperative is used - but the construction is just that, archaic. Except for effect / old times' sake, the regular negation ('do not tarry') (or more idiomatically, 'be quick about it') would always be chosen nowadays.

If a declarative sentence ***was*** intended, the construction is again archaic:

He knows not what to do. (archaic)

He doesn't know what to do. (modern idiomatic)

Comment: Thanks Edwin...Would the phrase in question communicate - un-know what you know or you don't know what you know?

Comment: Without context, it would communicate to me 'Read something else.'